# Java Web Start saving large amount of data into local system

Tags: java, file, serialization, java-web-start

Can Java Web Start application save lots of data (eg. MySQLite files) onto local system?  Is there a limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer: Java Web Start is a mechanism to get your application to the user's machine. Once on it, the application runs sandboxed and has access to local resources according to the policy. Make sure your application is signed and read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#security) for more information.

Comment: Note the differences between the older Java 6 description of security and the same in Java 8.  Java 6 - *"If an application requests full access, then all JAR files must be signed."*.  Java 8 *"All JAR files must be signed."*.  It is best to link to the latest documentation publicly available.  ;)  And given that, we can then declare nothing and be sand-boxed, or choose between `all-permissions` **and** the more limited `j2ee-application-client-permissions`.